# Physical Address Extension - how do virtual addresses work?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, pae

I'm running Debian Linux. `uname -m` says `i686` which means 32-bit architecture machine with `pae` flag enabled. `getconf LONG_BIT`  is `32`. Installed RAM capacity is 6GB.

My `/proc/cpuinfo` has an entry `address sizes  : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual`. However, my program is generating only 32 bit address. (`Address of x is 0xbfbaf5cc`)

I do not understand the relation between 48 bit virtual address shown by `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and the virtual address generated by the C program. Complete CPU info can be found [here.](https://gist.github.com/stamilselvan/3f17440929734d3310d4)

Could somebody explain?

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` is your physical CPU's capabilities. If your kernel & OS are 32bit, you'll only get 32bit addresses.

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Added [cpuinfo](https://gist.github.com/stamilselvan/3f17440929734d3310d4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) doesn't change anything about virtual addresses. As the name hints, it's only about physical addresses. As an application programmer, PAE doesn't change anything for you. Your program still has a 32-bit address space, out of which the kernel takes approximately 1 bit (Linux grants 1GB, 2GB or 3GB to userspace depending on compilation options). If you want a larger address space, you need a 64-bit system.

The point of PAE is to allow the kernel to address more than 4GB of physical RAM. In order to make use of all this RAM, you need multiple processes, each of which can map at most 2GB (or 1GB or 3GB).

In PAE mode, MMU tables map 32-bit virtual addresses to 40-bit physical addresses, with a three-level table (unlike non-PAE mode where the MMU tables map 32-bit virtual addresses to 32-bit physical addresses with a two-level table).

The indication “48 bits virtual” refers to the CPU's capabilities. I think this means that the CPU is a 64-bit one (i.e. one that supports [amd64 a.k.a. x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)). In order to make use of 48-bit virtual addresses, you'd need to run a 64-bit operating system. Here 48-bit is a little confusing for an application programmer: the CPU translates only 48 bits of the address, but the address is encoded in 64 bits — pointers occupy 8 bytes, not 6. The upper 16 bits can contain [additional tags used by the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219562/why-cant-os-use-entire-64-bits-for-addressing-why-only-the-48-bits).

Comment: My CPU is `64 bit` and installed OS is `32 bit`. That explains the reason of `48 bits virtual` address size. Above such machines `lscpu` will be like `Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit`

Answer (score 1):

[pae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) stand for *physical address extension* and allow a cpu with a 32bit address bus *to address* more than 4G.

Notice that if your `/proc/cpuinfo` show support for `pae` isn't enough, you need to use a kernel compiled  with `pae` options enabled (eg: I'm using a Debian prebuilt 3.16-2-686-pae)

The memory model/layout of a Linux process is defined by the Linux kernel and is (or anyway may be) different between architectures, a user process would never *see* the whole physical RAM (only the kernel), let say the kernel may allow the process to **theoretically** use 2G but then in real those are used only when needed with *pages* (usually each with size 4K or 16K) which the kernel *map* from the physical Ram into the process.